# Custom React Dropdown

Tags: reactjs

Would like to implement similira to `react-bootstrap` `Dropdown` where I can set `Dropdown.Header` and `Dropdown.Body` to any `React.ReactNode`. What currently have is this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

interface DropdownProps {
  children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
}

export const Dropdown = ({ children }: DropdownProps) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

interface HeaderProps {
  children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
}

export const Header = ({ children }: HeaderProps) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

interface BodyProps {
  children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
}

export const Body = ({ children }: BodyProps) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

var _default = Object.assign(Dropdown, {
  Header,
  Body,
});

export default _default;
```

It can be used like this:

```
return (
<Dropdown>
  <Dropdown.Header>
    <Image
      alt="LanguageImage"
      size="small"
      src={require(`../assets/images/languages/${userLanguage}.png`)}
    />
  </Dropdown.Header>
  <Dropdown.Body>
    {Object.entries(LanguageOptions).map(([id, name]) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <Image
            key={id}
            data-language={id}
            onClick={handleLanguageChange}
            alt="LanguageImage"
            size="small"
            title={name}
            src={require(`../assets/images/languages/${id}.png`)}
          />
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </Dropdown.Body>
</Dropdown>
```

My problem is that I cannot hide `Dropdown.Body` based on `isOpen` since it is completly different component. Do you have any suggestions how can I rework this to be as expected?

Comment: What I understand is, you want to hide only the `Body`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a context for the dropdown state

```
interface DropdownContextProps {
  isOpen: boolean;
  setIsOpen: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const DropdownContext = createContext({} as DropdownContextProps);
```

And define a provider for all the children components on Dropdown

```
export const Dropdown = ({ children }: DropdownProps) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <DropdownContext.Provider value={{ isOpen, setIsOpen }}>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </DropdownContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-estrela-s61v82) as an example